# How to never logout and never retype password App store

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, apple-id

Apple App store is really annoying with all their security. Is there a way to never logout and never retype your passwords?

I newer log out, but it seems something logs me out (sign out) automatically?

Comment: No @Buscar웃 I get signed out automatically it seems.

Comment: So how do you exit the app store ? using the Quit ?

Comment: yes that is correct @Buscar웃

Comment: do you have and use the Users switching on your Mac?

Comment: @Buscar웃 no. I don't know why apple asks for so many passwords so often? Even if I want to download a free app.

Comment: It does not ask for password for free app, and it does not log you out. The log out problem is on your site.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a 2 part question.

- Part 1 (Password)

Apple Store has 2 levels.

One is general level

you can stay always signed in to that one by simply not singing out.

It will know it is you since it will show your user name:

[image: app store]

It will show you your Updates and your Past Purchases.

The next level will always require you to confirm it is you. <sub>(what a strange English that was :)</sub>

If you want to make a Purchase or change your account settings then the Password is required.

- Now to the "Automatic"?? log out part.

Normally once logged in you will stay logged in. The Apple store does not log you out.

One possible reason would be if you change the Computer user, that would lead to log out of the Apple store.

Also your user account might have a problem, so try if you stay logged in in another user account (if you have one).

Comment: How does this answer the question "How to never need to logout"

Comment: @Mark if you know better answer don't be shy! I will respectfully remove mine.

Comment: See Graham Milne's second comment on his answer explains why I think his answer answer the question

Answer (score 1):

## Right: authenticate-appstore-30

Authorisation and authentication on Mac OS X are controlled [by rights](http://dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/). The App Store likely uses the [authenticate-appstore-30](http://dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/authenticate-appstore-30.html) right to determine who has the right to login and how long the authorisation should last.

By default the `authenticate-appstore-30` right times out after **30 minutes**.

## Changing the Right

You can change the `authenticate-appstore-30` right using the built-in [security](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) tool or another tool like [authbuddy](http://www.dssw.co.uk/authbuddy/).

To allow all users with no time out, the `security` command would be:

```
sudo security authorizationdb write authenticate-appstore-30 allow
```

To allow administrators only with no time out, the `authbuddy` command would be:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/authbuddy set authenticate-appstore-30 administrator
```

Adjusting rights is prone to causing problems; be careful. Der Flounder walks through the process for setting and testing in this article, [Managing the Authorization Database in OS X Mavericks](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/managing-the-authorization-database-in-os-x-mavericks/).

Comment: why would the "rights" be broken in first place?

Comment: I am not sure what is considered broken in this case. The initial rights are set by Apple. The time out of this right is part of OS X's default behaviour to protect their customers.

Comment: you are recommending to fix it, so it is broken. As for me, the log in newer expires so it is not broken for me?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. In this case @love-learning wants behaviour different from the OS X default. To achieve this, the associated right can be altered. I do not see it as broken or wrong; only different settings for different people.

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong, just considering the heavy duty operation for a novice user, as you pointed it out in your answer.